# How to get subscriber's destination in SCP multitanant app

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

The situation is i have a multitanant app running on SCP. some customers will subscribe my app. They will define their own destination for external system. I have set up the could-connector. Another thing is my app have no request context ,it's just based on schedule task.

Env: SCP Cloudfoundry

I have try to get destination from provider side successfully. but failed for subscriber side.

the code snipt below is how i get destination

```
    log.info("==========Begin logic to get destination==========");
    Callable<Destination> callable = new Callable<Destination>() {
      @Override
      public Destination call() throws Exception {
        DestinationAccessor
            .setRetrievalStrategy("xxx", DestinationRetrievalStrategy.ALWAYS_SUBSCRIBER);
        return DestinationAccessor.getDestination("xxx");
      }
    };
    return new RequestContextExecutor().execute(callable);
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what the failure looks like?

Comment: Hi Sander Wozniak.the error message is like:com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: 
 Failed to get destinations of provider service instance:
 Failed to get access token for destination service. 
 If your application is running on Cloud Foundry, make sure to have a binding to both the destination service and the authorization and trust management (xsuaa) service,
 AND that you either properly secured your application or have set the \"ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER\" environment variable to true.

Comment: just now, i have update my SDK version and have a try with JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor.onBehalfOfTenant(xxx).execute(callable).waiting deploy and check results...hope success~

Comment: Did you do the setup for multi-tenancy? This involves adding an endpoint to your app for the destination service? This is invoked by the SAP CP infrastructure when doing a subscription.

Comment: yes, all need set up has been done.i have test subscribe with another subaccount  include saas registry also been set up

Comment: Hi  Sander Wozniak . after I test with JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor , an error says :Failed to build RequestContextListenerChain: there are two listeners with the same priority -5. This is not allowed. Conflicting listeners: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor$JwtBasedAuthTokenRequestContextListener, com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor$JwtBasedAuthTokenRequestContextListener.

Comment: is there any configuration should i do? i am not sure. do you have some code snippet

Comment: Pls be so kind and update your question above with the _current_ code. It is difficult to follow your changes when you post it in the comments only. Also pls put the stack trace of the error and format your question to make it readable.

Answer (score 3):

### For SAP Cloud SDK version 2:

This version needs some extra information for `JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor.onBehalfOfTenant` to work. For each tenant you want to operate on, the following are needed:

1. The tenant ID. When making the application subscription-ready you had to implement a subscription callback endpoint that SCP calls whenever a tenant subscribes to your application. The URL that SCP calls contains the tenant ID which you can extract. Your callback servlet should now persist this tenant ID somewhere.
2. A fully-qualified URI to the tenant's XSUAA instance. Part of this you can also get from the subscription callback endpoint. SCP calls your endpoint with a JSON payload that contains a property called `subscribedSubdomain`. Your callback servlet should now persist this somewhere along with the tenant ID. This takes care of the host name portion but `JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor` needs a full XSUAA URI (e.g. `https://[subscribedSubdomain].[uaadomain]`). One way is to get the provider's XSUAA information and extract the `uaadomain` parameter (basically loading from `VCAP_SERVICES`) using `CloudPlatformAccessor`, like so:

   ```java
   final String tenantXsuaaUri = "https://" + subscribedSubdomain + "." + ((ScpCfCloudPlatform)CloudPlatformAccessor.getCloudPlatform()).getXsuaaServiceCredentials().get("uaadomain").getAsString();
   ```
3. XS application name of provider's XSUAA instance. For this you can use the `CloudPlatformAccessor` like so (again, loading from `VCAP_SERVICES`):

   ```java
   final String xsAppName = ((ScpCfCloudPlatform)CloudPlatformAccessor.getCloudPlatform()).getXsAppName();
   ```

Once you finally have all the needed parameters, you can call `JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor.onBehalfOfTenant` like so to run something as the desired tenant:

```java
new JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor()
    .onBehalfOfTenant(tenantId, tenantXsuaaUri, Collections.singletonList(xsAppName))
    .withParentRequestContext()
    .execute(() -> {

    // your code goes here

});
```

### For SAP Cloud SDK version 3:

This version has been improved and it is easier to execute code as another tenant, so I would recommend upgrading to version 3 if possible. With version 3 you only need the tenant ID and the `subscribedSubdomain` value (no need to form a complete XSUAA URI). Instead of `JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor` you would use the `TenantAccessor` class and the `executeWithTenant` method like so:

```java
final Tenant subscribedTenant = new ScpCfTenant(tenantID, subscribedSubdomain);

TenantAccessor.executeWithTenant(subscribedTenant, () -> {

    // your code goes here

});
```

Overview of SAP Cloud SDK version 3:
https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/01/version-3-of-the-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java-is-here/

Version 3 Migration Guide:
https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/01/migrate-to-version-3.0.0-of-the-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/

Version 3 release notes:
https://help.sap.com/doc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html